# I can not load model which contains custom_objects in the tensorflow even thought I train and test the model in same python version

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem about loading model when I Recurrence an excellent paper. After training the model , I encounter the problem "**SystemError: unknown opcode**" when I load the model to pretict my data. The load function include **custom_objects**.

My development environment as fellow:

python 3.6.0, tensorflow 1.15.0

My code as fellow:

```
    checkpoint = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(
    checkpoint_path,
    custom_objects={'<lambda>': lambda x, y: y,
                    'tf': tf}
)
```

Here is my error:

```
    File "E:/OCR_model/2022-5_Improving convolutional models for handwritten text recognition/Easter2-main/src/my_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test_on_iam(show=False, partition="validation", checkpoint=checkpoint_path, uncased=True)
  File "E:\OCR_model\2022-5_Improving convolutional models for handwritten text recognition\Easter2-main\src\predict.py", line 72, in test_on_iam
    model = load_easter_model(checkpoint)
  File "E:\OCR_model\2022-5_Improving convolutional models for handwritten text recognition\Easter2-main\src\predict.py", line 33, in load_easter_model
    'tf': tf}
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 143, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 162, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1081, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1039, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 854, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3_4_2_0\install\envs\py36_tf1_15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 789, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "E:/OCR_model/2022-5_Improving convolutional models for handwritten text recognition/Easter2-main/src/easter_model.py", line 31, in ctc_custom
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
SystemError: unknown opcode
```